# Горячие клавиши в VS code (codium)

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

Подскажите комбинацию клавиш, для открытия исходного кода объекта, в VS code. Например, чтобы при импорте класса, когда выделяешь его с этой комбинацией  можно было открыть его исходники.

Comment: Попробуйте удерживать ctrl и нажать стрелкой мышки

Comment: В `VSCodium` на сегодня не реализовано это. А в `VSCode` есть плагин который встроен и называется `go-to-difinition` (вроде так). Но так же работает не корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F12 - перейти к определению и Ctrl+Shift+F10 - быстрый показ в той же вкладке.

Эти комбинации будут работать только если редактор в состоянии парсить структуру. Например, для lua по умолчанию не работает, нужно устанавливать плагин вроде EmmyLua.

Comment: Да работает, но нужно предустановить ms-python.python. Спасибо.